# How to switch different strings from file in a while loop using Perl

Tags: perl, cmd

I have a question, it is probably an easy one, but I haven't found the answer for it.

I have a file of strings (each string in a separate line, and I need to use each string (line) in the cmd.

I'm using a 'while' loop, but I don't know how to append each string to the loop.

I need to run the following when the XXX.XXX.XXX is the string that needs to be changed in the loop.

```
c:\putty\putty.exe -ssh "root@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX" -pw "password" -m "c:\putty\putty.txt"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die $!;

while (my $line = <$fh>)
{
    chomp $line;

    #Here you can replace 'XXX.XXX.XXX' with '$line'. Modify below line as per your requirement. 
    my $cmd = `c:\\putty\\putty.exe -ssh "root\@$line" -pw "password" -m "c:\\putty\\putty.txt"`;
}
close $fh;
```

Answer (score 1):

More detailed version would be:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "file_of_strings.file";

# Open file and read contents before closing handle
open(FH, "<", $file) or die "Unable to open \"$file\" $!";
chomp(my @users = <FH>);
close(FH);

for my $user (@users) { 
    # Frame remote command
    my $cmd = "c:\putty\putty.exe -ssh 'root\@${user}' -pw 'password' -m 'c:\putty\putty.txt'";

    if (system $cmd != 0) {    # system command returns 0 on successful execution
        print "Successfully executed command: $cmd\n";
    } else {    
        print "Failed to execute command: $cmd exited $? $!\n"; # Better to log the exit code ($?) and error message, if any($!).
    }
}
```

Comment: Its good practice to use lexical filehandle $FH, and if file size will be big, its not a good idea of taking whole file contents into memory.